# How to handle different post sources in Asp.NET MVC with a strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Say I have a model that maps a person and I want to build a view for this model having some text inputs and a series of drop-downs to select state, province, city.

I'm adding `@onchange = "this.form.submit()"` in each `@Html.DropDownListFor` to post back to the server and drill-down the selection on those drop-downs.

How can I understand in my controller the source of said post? How do I distinguish the post coming from a drop-down change to the one coming from a submit button?

Comment: "> I'm adding `@onchange = "this.form.submit()"` in each `@Html.DropDownListFor` to post back to the server and drill-down the selection on those drop-downs." - **please don't do this** for many reasons (namely, it breaks the user's back button) and can be a jarring user-experience. Instead use a normal AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

While not being able to understand the exact source of the postback, based on [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework) I'm at least able to check if the source was one of the submit buttons by simply checking:

```
if(Request.Form["submitButtonNameAttribute"] != null)
```

When multiple buttons are available, only the clicked one is `!= null` at postback.

Still, this is not a complete solution related to the original answer, but while a button may indicate an action to be run, other changes in the view may just invoke some sync work on the model.